# how to make a generic comparator method

Tags: java, list, arraylist, comparator

i have a utility class and i want to have a generic method for sorting so that, and arrayList of any type passed to this static method posted below, 
the will be sorted.

when i write the below code, eclipse asks to add the unimplemented methods, and when i  accept adding them , i found that they are too many and i 
do not know which one should i use

**CODE**:

```
public static <T> void sortAsc(ArrayList<T> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, ascOrder);
}

private static Comparator<T> ascOrder = new Comparator<T>() {

    public int compare(DMatch arg0, DMatch arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return Float.compare(arg0.distance, arg1.distance);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you- you want to write a helper method that get's a list of any type and sort it? by what?

Comment: @yes, by "distance " for an exaple

Comment: Are you using Java 8? If so look at the interface `Comparator`. It now contains many static methods returning `Comparator<T>`. In your example you'd have to type `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingDouble(x->x.distance))` or something.

Comment: If there are no type restrictions how would you know that the objects contain the distance property?

Comment: The `Comparator` interface in Java 8 already has many utility methods for this kind of thing. You could for example do `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(DMatch::getDistance)));`

Comment: @rmaik what's "distance" for 2 DatabaseConnection objects?

Comment: @AndersonVieira sorry i think i am mistaken, generic comparator would not suit my application....should i delete the question..please advise

Comment: @rmaik I don't think you can delete it anymore. But if you understand the problem better now, you can edit the question and make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you're trying to do you need a type that ensures there will be a `getDistance()` method.  That can be an abstract class or an interface.  Whichever it is I'm calling it HasDistance.

```
public static void sortAsc(ArrayList<? extends HasDistance> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, ascOrder);
}

private static Comparator<HasDistance> ascOrder = new Comparator<>() {

    public int compare(HasDistance arg0, HasDistance arg1) {
        return Float.compare(arg0.getDistance(), arg1.getDistance());
    }
};
```

Comment: The return type of `ascOrder` should be changed to `Comparator<HasDistance>`. Otherwise it won't be possible to use it.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I'm not following you.  `ascOrder` is not a method, thus has no return type.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I meant it should have type `Comparator<HasDistance>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort "any type" then you will need to pick something that will work with "any type".  Essentially, you want to sort a list of `Object`.  That will probably limit you to comparing `myObject.hashCode()` or `myObject.toString()`.  Pick one or the other and stick with it consistently.  Whether or not the ordering you get from either of these methods will be useful is a completely different question.

If you can make the contents of your list less general, then you will have a wider range of options to sort on.

Answer (score 0):

After Java 8 you can just use yourList.sort(param).
The method param can be a Comparator or null if the items in your list implements Comparable interface.